# Recreate Fragments on BackKey Pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Im trying to Solve a problem where when a user press back key, the fragment should be recreated rather than loading from back stack. I have a single Main activity with a frame layout and i replace the fragments within the single frame dynamically. the code below works when the user go from fragment within fragment. but when the user select from navigation drawer, the replaced fragment is going on to the top of backstack which is causing problems.

Right now the code i wrote in BackKey Pressed Event

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
        {

            Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager.IBackStackEntry entry =
                SupportFragmentManager.GetBackStackEntryAt(SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount - 1);

            string str = entry.Name;                   

            if (SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount == 0)
            {
                this.Finish();
            }                
            else
            {
                Fragment fr = (Fragment)MagicallyCreateInstance(str);
                SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fr).Commit();   
                SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStack();

            }                    
            base.OnBackPressed();
        }
```

i also have a replace fragment method which i use to replace fragments. but in this process the back key is getting disabled by default somehow (Not sure how) but whenever there is existing fragment in the backstack, the old UI is getting loaded. Can i refresh the layout here?

```
public void ReplaceFragment(Fragment fragment, FragmentManager fragmentManager)
        {
            string backStateName = fragment.Class.SimpleName;
            bool fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

            if (!fragmentPopped && fragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null)
            {
                fragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                               .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment).SetTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TransitFragmentFade)
                               .AddToBackStack(backStateName)
                               .Commit();
            }

        }
```

Can anyone please help me solve this any one of the above?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your problem correctly. But it sounds like you want to make sure that when the user selects a destination from your main navigation you want to make sure the back stack is cleared or reset.

Ex:

```
Stack looks like this:
A->B->C
User selects D from main navigation, stack should look like:
D

NOT
A->B->C->D
```

If this is the case, you should clear the back stack before navigating to any top-level destinations. This can be done like so:

```
FragmentManager.PopBackStack(null, FragmentManager.PopBackStackInclusive);
```

The documentation for this method is not great, but it will pop everything off the back stack. A discussion can be found here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/0qXCA9rW7EI/M9riRM0kl9QJ

Comment: Yes you are correct, and also im trying to solve how to handle back navigation from C -> B-> A when the user press back button. and which is the best place to handle the back navigation. Activity or Fragments?

Comment: I usually let Android handle the back navigation, I.E. I don't handle back button events in the app. What you have in your `OnBackPressed` method is essentially what android does for you. If you are adding fragment transactions to the back stack they will pop off when back is pressed. And the app will exit when back is pressed and the back stack becomes empty.

Comment: Thanks. i actually had to write Extra handle situations in my Replace fragment class to handle the fragments replace, so that back stack can be handled by the OS perfectly.